# Windows-PowerPoint presentations on an iPad with great typography distortion

Tags: ios, ms-office, font

I have a PowerPoint presentation created on Microsoft Windows. When I play it on an iPad there are great typography distortions. There are a lot of fonts not found on the by iPad. Could I install my own fonts on an iPad, or solve this in another way?

Comment: Are you viewing the Microsoft PowerPoint presentation on Apple Keynote for iPad?

Comment: Well, the same happens with this apps: Keynote, Documents to go and Quickoffice. When I try to open a .ppt created on my windows PC with comic sans or another windows based typography not standard on the iPad the result is catastrophic.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the iPad does not support the installation of fonts by the user, and microsoft office documents do not allow font embedding. If you wish to maintain consistent typography you'll have to use a document that supports font embedding such as a PDF.

Answer (score 4):

In order to obtain similar results in typography on a Windows PC running PowerPoint and on an iPad, perhaps you should construct your PowerPoint presentation with fonts that are already available on the iPad.

Apple's [list of fonts in iOS 5 is here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4980?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

If you want things to look the same on different platforms, it is always a good idea to restrict your presentations to the basic fonts Arial, Courier, Georgia, Times New Roman and Verdana.

Comment: Could be a great idea if (in the future) the default Keynote and other apps font translation were to the same or inferior size, in order to prevent such distortion.

Comment: The problem with this is that point size doesn't necessarily translate to the same thing across typefaces, different type foundries tend to make their fonts different sizes.